# how to request for license=cc0 photos by places api

Tags: google-places-api

I use the api https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchText to get an array of places

by this results I use https://places.googleapis.com/v1/ photos[0].name /media?maxWidthPx=374&skipHttpRedirect=true&key=mykey to get the main photo

how can I ensure to use the photo without license (CC0 public domain)??

I did not find any filter to set the license, but otherwise the requested photos are not useable

thanks in advance

Peter

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms should answer your question/s around the license and how to use (everything you get out of) the Places API.